# Web scraping from finishline.com using BS4 or Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from https://www.finishline.com using either Selenium or Beautifulsoup 4. So far I have been unsuccessful so I've turned to Stackoverflow for assistance - hoping that someone knows a way around their scraping protection.

I tried using Beautifulsoup 4 and Selenium. Below are some simple examples.

General imports used in my main program:

```
import requests
import csv
import io
import os
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Beautifulsoup 4 code:

```
data2 = requests.get("https://www.finishline.com/store/product/mens-nike-air-max-95-se-casual-shoes/prod2783292?styleId=AJ2018&colorId=004")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(data2.text, 'html.parser')

x = soup2.find('h1', attrs={'id': 'title'}).text.strip()
print(x)
```

Selenium code:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.finishline.com/store/product/mens-nike-air-max-95-se-casual-shoes/prod2783292?styleId=AJ2018&colorId=004") 
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[1]")
print(x)
driver.close()
```

Both of those snippets are attempts at getting the product title from the product page.

The Beautifulsoup 4 snippet sometimes just gets stuck and does nothing, and other times it returns

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10060, 'WSAETIMEDOUT')"))
```

The Selenium snippet returns

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b3707fb7d7b201e2fa30dabbedec32c5", element="0.10646785765405364-1")>
```

which means it did find the element, but when I try to convert it to text by changing

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[1]")
```

to

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[1]").text
```

it returns `Access Denied`, which is also what the site itself sometimes returns in the browser. It can be bypassed by clearing cookies.

Does anyone know of a way to scrape data from this website? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requests is rejected by server because of user agents, i added user agent to the request.

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'
}
data2 = requests.get("https://www.finishline.com/store/product/mens-nike-air-max-95-se-casual-shoes/prod2783292?styleId=AJ2018&colorId=004",headers=headers)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(data2.text, 'html.parser')

x = soup2.find('h1', attrs={'id': 'title'}).text.strip()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
Men's Nike Air Max 95 SE Casual Shoes
```

Comment: I forgot to include my headers that I was previously using unsuccessfully, however with your headers it does seem to work. Thank you very much, my problem seems to be solved!

Answer (score 1):

Try as this, for me it works, it returns `MEN'S NIKE AIR MAX 95 SE CASUAL SHOES`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.finishline.com/store/product/mens-nike-air-max-95-se-casual-shoes/prod2783292?styleId=AJ2018&colorId=004")
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="title"]')
print(x.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does work. For this specific program I decided to use BS4